# Intel icpc and C++14: How to constexpr std::complex?

Tags: c++, c++14, complex-numbers, icc

In my calculations I use the imaginary unit and I think that the compiler should be able to simplify these operations at compile time by reducing things like

```
a + i b --> std::complex(a,b)
```

Of course the above is simplified and my expressions usually look more complex (pun intended).

In C++14 I can use the complex literals for that, whereas in C++11 I was using a `constexpr std::complex` variable.  However, both of these methods fail with the Intel C++ Compiler `icpc` with the error messages as comments in the source.

How can I work around these glitches?

```
#include <complex>

auto test1(double a, double b)
{
  // error #1909: complex integral types are not supported
  using namespace std::complex_literals;
  auto z = a + 1i*b;
  return z;
}

auto test2(double a, double b)
{
  // error: calling the default constructor for "std::complex<double>" does not produce a constant value
  constexpr std::complex<double> I(0,1);
  auto z = a + I*b;
  return z;
}

auto test3(double a, double b)
{
  // Can this be optimized as good as the others?
  std::complex<double> I(0,1);
  auto z = a + I*b;
  return z;
}
```

*Bonus question:* Why is `test2` optimized away and replaced by a jump to `test3`? (see https://godbolt.org/g/pW1JZ8)

Comment: The `test2` optimization is simply because the compiler is allowed to emit code like that; it follows the as-if rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error on complex literals is self-explanatory. The version of the intel compiler I got handy (16.0.3) neither supports them.

When it comes to the second error, I'd say it mostly depends on the GCC standard library version you are using, because icpc does not ship a (complete) standard library. I have installed GCC 5.4 and your `test2` function compiles correctly.

What should make the difference is whether the constructor of `std::complex` is anotated `constexpr`. In GCC 5.4 it is:

> ```
>        _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR complex(const _Tp& __r = _Tp(), const _Tp& __i = _Tp())
>   : _M_real(__r), _M_imag(__i) { }
> ```

Comment: My code compiles on the same machine with GCC and Clang which both use `stdlibc++`, which is the one ICC apparently uses as well, yet it does not work in ICC.

Comment: @HenriMenke Are you using the `-std=c++14` flag? This works for me: `echo "#include <complex>" > foo.cpp`, `echo "auto test2(double a, double b) { constexpr std::complex<double> I(0,1); return a + I*b; }" >> foo.cpp` and `icpc -std=c++14 -c foo.cpp`

Comment: Yes, I am using `-std=c++14` with ICC 17.0.2.

Comment: @HenriMenke I see. It seems that libstdc++ has an especialiation for `std::complex<double>` that icpc 17 doen't like for constexpr-evaluation, yet it does work with icpc 16. Anyway, as you noted, the compiler should be pretty good at optimizing away these constant values.